# Proper surjective holomorphic function is a topological bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, smooth-manifolds, foliations

If I have $u:M\rightarrow D\setminus 0$, $M\subseteq (\mathbb C^2,0)$ compact, $\mathbb C^2 = \mathbb C \times \mathbb C$ and $D$ the Poincare disk, $u$ is holomorphic, surjective, proper and every point in $D\setminus 0$ is a regular value.
How can i see that it defines a topological bundle?

My idea of demonstration was to use Frobenius theorem, since $M$ is foliated by the integral curves of $V=-u_{w}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}+u_{z}\frac{\partial}{\partial w}$ (we can ''split'' this vector field into two real ones) and the theorem says that for every point $p\in M$ there is a chart $(U,\varphi)$ such that $\varphi (U)$ is a cube and the integral surfaces of $\varphi (U)$ 
are the slices with the two last coordinates equal to constants. After this i don't know what to do.

Comment: You might be interested in this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehresmann's_lemma

Comment: @DenisNardin  will look at it. Hope can understand the proof. thanks

Comment: I found this serie of vector fields, flows,... excercises to prove The Ehresmann  Fibration theorem. If someone is interested. 
chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~behre001/AoM/AoM_exercises_11.pdf